# Switching camera to follow object in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I'm trying to switch one camera to another to follow the sphere. What's happening in my script is, at first the main camera focuses the ball and as soon as it is grabbed and thrown, the main camera is switched off or disabled and the second camera is enabled to follow the ball when it is in motion. But the second camera doesn't follow in the direction of the ball. Below is the scripts that i implemented.

**Note:- I'm attaching the second camera script at run time to second camera.**

**PickupObject.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class pickupobject : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject mainCamera;
    //public GameObject empty;
    bool carrying;
    public GameObject carriedObject;
    // Camera cam;
    public float distances;
    public float smooth;
    float speed = 1000f;
    private Vector3 offset;
    public Camera camera;

    private MovingBall script;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //cam = GameObject.Find("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
        mainCamera = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera");
        camera = GameObject.FindWithTag("secondCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T) && carrying)
        {
            carrying = !carrying;
            ThrowBall();
        }
        if (carrying)
        {
            carry(carriedObject);
            // CheckDrop();
        }
        else
        {
            pickup();
        }


    }

    private void pickup()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {

            int x = Screen.width / 2;
            int y = Screen.height / 2;
            Ray ray = mainCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(x, y));
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                pickupable p = hit.collider.GetComponent<pickupable>();

                if (p != null)
                {
                    carrying = true;
                    carriedObject = p.gameObject;


                    camera.enabled = true;

                    camera.gameObject.AddComponent<CameraController>();
                    carriedObject.AddComponent<MovingBall>();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    void carry(GameObject o)
    {
        o.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        o.transform.position = mainCamera.transform.position + mainCamera.transform.forward * distances;

    }


    //void CheckDrop()
    //{
    //    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.U))
    //    {
    //        Drop();
    //    }
    //}

    //void Drop()
    //{
    //    ThrowBall();

    //}
    void ThrowBall()
    {
        mainCamera.SetActive(false);

        carriedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;

        carriedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(0f, 0f, speed);


    }

}
```

**CameraController.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization

    public GameObject icosphere;
    private Vector3 offset;
    pickupobject ball = new pickupobject();


    void Start () {
        ball.camera = GameObject.FindWithTag("secondCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
        //offset = transform.position - icosphere.transform.position;
        //icosphere = GameObject.FindWithTag("yellowball");
        // icosphere = ball.carriedObject.GetComponent<GameObject>();
        offset = ball.camera.transform.position - GameObject.FindWithTag("purpleball").transform.position;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate () {

        ball.camera.transform.position = GameObject.FindWithTag("purpleball").transform.position + offset;
       // transform.position = ball.carriedObject.GetComponent<GameObject>().transform.position + offset;

    }


}
```

Comment: I would create another camera as a child of the "purpleball" game object and disable/enable it as needed instead of finding the gameobject every frame and setting camera position.

Comment: I Think this might be your problem: `pickupobject ball = new pickupobject();` try to get the one you already made instead of making a new one.

Comment: @jjhavokk I have to attach the camera script to more sphere one after another. Thats y i didn't make any child for the purple ball.

Comment: @Hristo could you please tell me a little more so that i can make changes accordingly.

Comment: Replace the line `pickupobject ball = new pickupobject();` with `public GameObject ball; ` Then in Unity, pass the `GameObject` that has the `PickupObject.cs` attached as a component.

Comment: Well its the carried object which you are referring to i guess, but the carried object itself is not referenced to any gameobject in unity, so how can i pass the carried object without tag?

Comment: is this how you are trying to explain?
icosphere = GetComponent<pickupobject>().carriedObject;

Comment: Have you tried that?

Comment: You can pass the object by Dragging it physically with the mouse in Unity

Comment: I did try the line of code i mentioned in my last comment, but it outputs an error. Beside this, i cannot drag the carried object in unity because in my pickupobject script it is not a referenced GameObject.

Comment: So let me explain what this `pickupobject ball = new pickupobject();` does. In your first script you have some `public` variables, i.e. _smooth_,_camera_,_distances_ etc.. You are probably setting those values wherever your script is attached, so far so good. Whenever you make a new `pickupobject ball` as you are doing, All the values that you used are disregarded, because you are creating a fresh object. Instead you should be using your existing `pickupobject` as a reference.

Comment: @Hristo, Thanks for the wonderful explanation, the issue that happening now is, I am unable to follow the second camera after the ball, whenever the ball is thrown the camera stays at its original position.

Comment: and how would i use the existing "pickupobject" as a reference to my "CameraController" class so as to access the carried object from the "pickupobject" class?